# Need assistance for attaching audio to alert box

Tags: javascript, html, audio, alert, attachment

I am making a website for an art installation that show's how computers engage with humans and can seem human, in some ways. To do this I need alerts to go in a particular order. Attaching audio to the specific alert that is being shown. I am going to have over 5 alerts in total, with 5 wav. that are voice files readings what the alert box will be saying.

I've been working on this for hours now, and way to frustrated to think properly. I do not know javascript at all, so please, any suggests will be beyond my knowledge in this language.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 var audio = new Audio('Images/hellllloooo.wav');
        audio.oncanplay  = function() {
            audio.play();
            alert("Hello?");
        };

        </script>
        <script>

    var audio = new Audio('Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav');
        audio.oncanplay  = function() {
            audio.play();
            alert("sorry?");
        };
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your current code do? oh, I see, because you're using `oncanplay` making the code asynchronous

Comment: `alert` is extremely user unfriendly (and *blocks*, too), are you sure that it's what you want?

Comment: I want it to be extremely unfriendly

Comment: Currently the code shows both alerts, while only playing the 1st audio for the second one

Comment: How can I connect the audio portion to the alert portion and keep them together lol

Comment: simply, you can't

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your example is to "nest" the two bits of code, such that the second alert waits for the first

```
var audio = new Audio('Images/hellllloooo.wav');
audio.oncanplay  = function() {
    audio.play();
    alert("Hello?");
    var audio2 = new Audio('Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav');
    audio2.oncanplay  = function() {
        audio2.play();
        alert("sorry?");
    };
};
```

Of course, doing it like this, the nesting gets messy past about 2, and you want 5

So, I would recommend using Promises

```
function playAlert(msg, wav) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var audio = new Audio(wav);
        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
            audio.play();
            alert(msg);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
playAlert("Hello?", 'Images/hellllloooo.wav')
.then(function() {
    return playAlert("sorry?", 'Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav');
})
.then(function() {
    return playAlert("another message", 'Images/another.wav');
})
.then(function() {
    return playAlert("fourth message", 'Images/fourth.wav');
})
.then(function() {
    return playAlert("fifth message", 'Images/fifth.wav');
});
```

Above in modern javascript

```
const playAlert = (msg, wav) => new Promise(resolve => new Audio(wav).addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
    this.play();
    alert(msg);
    resolve();
}));

playAlert("Hello?", 'Images/hellllloooo.wav')
.then(() => playAlert("sorry?", 'Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav'))
.then(() => playAlert("another message", 'Images/another.wav'))
.then(() => playAlert("fourth message", 'Images/fourth.wav'))
.then(() => playAlert("fifth message", 'Images/fifth.wav'));
```

or even

```
[
    {"Hello?", 'Images/hellllloooo.wav'},
    {"sorry?", 'Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav'},
    {"another message", 'Images/another.wav'},
    {"fourth message", 'Images/fourth.wav'},
    {"fifth message", 'Images/fifth.wav'}
].reduce((p, {msg, wav}) => p.then(() => new Promise(resolve => new Audio(wav).addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
    this.play();
    alert(msg);
    resolve();
})), Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: is there anyway to have this be var timeoutID;?

Comment: what var timeoutID? I see nothing in the question about timeouts

Comment: How can you delay the appearance of the alerts? Rather than having them first appear in the page, how do you insert a timeout to them?

Comment: By using settimeout i guess

Comment: there's a new question with some useful answers that actually cover that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49569310/nested-promise-with-settimeout