# Nested Promise with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, nested, settimeout

I have a nested promise. The promise resolves or rejects based on another promise resolving or rejecting with a setTimeout of 0 so as not to clog:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promiseInst
    .then(value => {
      executeSoon(() => {
        dispatch({ ...action, status: "done", value: value });
        resolve(value);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      executeSoon(() => {
        dispatch({
          ...action,
          status: "error",
          error: error.message || error
        });
        reject(error);
      });
    });
});
```

the `executeSoon()` is `executeSoon(fn) { setTimeout(fn, 0); }`

How do I simplify this? Tried to get rid of the outer promise wrapper and returning the inner promise directly but got stuck with the resolve and reject not being defined. So I thought I'd just return a `Promise.resolve(value)` from inside the .then and `Promise.reject(error)` from the catch, but this does not work either. I feel it might be possible to simplify this, but can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: Could you explain what the purpose of the setTimeout(..0) is? "So as not to clog"?

Comment: Oh, the explicit promise construction antipattern :(

Comment: @JonasW.: Well, that's the only way the OP can use their `executeSoon`, since it's not promise-enabled. All we did in our answers was bury that `new Promise` in the utility function instead. :-) (If it's even needed.)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think it is so as to dispatch the action as soon as the event loop is empty. Reading T.J.Crowder's comment below I'd like it to fire when the engine is free to do so, but from what I understand relying on promises only will force it to fire after the macrotask, even if there are still things to be done.

Comment: @lukas then this other work should resolve the promise

Answer (score 1):

Just use a promising timer:

```
  const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Then its as simple as:

```
  timer(0).then(() => promiseInst)
   .then(...)
   .catch(...)
```

.... but actually you dont need the timer as promises are guaranteed to resolve one tick after `resolve()` was called.

Comment: *"...promises are guaranteed to resolve one tick after `resolve()` was called"* Not quite. A `then` handler is guaranteed to be called asynchronously. On browsers, it's called as a microtask immediately after the macrotask (the usual event loop) that scheduled it completes (before other macrotasks start, even if they were scheduled before the promise handler callback). `setTimeout` schedules a macrotask callback.

Comment: @t.j i rather take the nodejs vocab as it is more clear than the browser chaos

Comment: No chaos I'm aware of. In any case, Node doesn't just have two tiers like browsers, it has **three**. And I don't recall ever seeing any documentation for them (whereas browser tasks are covered in the WHAT-WG spec's [event loops](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#event-loops) section).

Comment: Ah, they **do** document it (now): https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a `then` handler is *always* executed asychronously, there's no need for `setTimeout(..., 0)` in the normal case. So if the `setTimeout` doesn't have another purpose:

```
return promiseInst
    .then(value => {
        dispatch({ ...action, status: "done", value: value });
        return value;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ ...action, status: "error", error: error.message || error });
        throw error;
    });
```

If it does something important, I'd probably have a promise-enabled version, something along these lines:

```
const setTimeoutPromise = (delay = 0) => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
});
```

Then see the lines with `***` below:

```
return promiseInst
    .then(value => setTimeoutPromise().then(() => value) // ***
    .then(value => {
        dispatch({ ...action, status: "done", value: value });
        return value;
    })
    .catch(error => setTimeoutPromise().then(() => {     // ***
        dispatch({ ...action, status: "error", error: error.message || error });
        throw error;
    })); // <== *** Note one more )
```

Comment: If I understand your comment below correctly getting rid of the setTimeout will force the code to fire after the macrotask, even if there are other tasks still queued. And with the setTimeout the action will fire when the event loop is empty?

Comment: @Lukas: Not quite. The simplest way to put it is: The call to `dispatch` will always be asynchronous, it's just that without the `setTimeout`, it'll happen a bit earlier than it would with the `setTimeout`. Being a bit more detailed: Browsers have "macrotasks" (callbacks to DOM event handlers, to `setTimeout` handlers, etc.) and "microtasks" (callbacks to promise resolution/rejection handlers). All JS code runs as part of some macrotask. When a promise is resolved, callbacks are queued as microtasks that will run at the end of the macrotask in which the promise was resolved.

Comment: (Or if you add a handler to a promise that's *already* settled, that will queue the microtask, which will run at the end of the macrotask where you added the handler.)